Download blob to a path using azure blob java sdk with UTF-8 encoded file name
I have blobs in a folder location and sometimes the blob name has some Chinese characters in it. For example, I have blob name as 项目.xlsx. Currently I am using downloadToFile method where am trying to download blob directly to my location. Here I couldn't specify UTF-8 encoding by any params or anything.
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobItem.getName());
blobClient.downloadToFile("C:/check/"+"项目.xlsx");

But in location if I give URL.encoder(项目.xlsx), its working fine, but I want the file name to be preserved. When I try to download, am getting unrecognized characters and marked with ? in the chinese characters file name.Is it possible by some way I can download the file to my local/azure file-share by having UTF-8 encoding so that Chinese characters are preserved? Please provide if any sample code is present.

You encountered a shortcoming of Windows …

Do you mean it is OS issue and not anything to related to azure blob storage?

When I try to download, am getting unrecognized characters and marked with ? in the chinese characters file name WHERE are you getting them? What does Windows Explorer say?

@antoclinton – Jepp! To verify that, try it on a Linux system. Or write a simple Java program that does nothing else than creating a file with the name 项目.xlsx and write some stuff to it. And there are differences between FAT (in all its incarnations) and NTFS. (Sorry, I do not have any Windows box at hand to try it myself)

Interesting. I see vfat allows that filename

Do you see regular ? (U+003F,  Question Mark) or something like � (U+FFFD,  Replacement Character) which is in fact  Glyph 0: the .notdef glyph?

@JosefZ: ...  am getting unrecognized characters and marked with ? in the chinese characters file name

@Venkatesan, you're somewhat repeating yourself, and inaccurately, as UTF-16 is used for file names afaik. It might be Ansi in certain limited areas
